# Const reference to temporary object does not extend its lifetime

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I have a class from which I create a temporary object. I can bind a const-reference to this temporary object, and it works as expected. However, if I call a member function, which returns std::move(*this), on this temporary object, and bind to this return value, it does not work as I expected. The short code below reproduces my problem and is self-explanatory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

class myval {
    public:
    std::vector<int> i;
    myval(int i) : i({i}) {}
    myval(const myval& v) = delete;
    myval(myval&& v) : i(std::move(v.i)) {}
    myval&& addone() && {
        i[0]++;
        return std::move(*this);
    }

};

int main()
{
    //Object is moved, works like expected
    const auto moved_value = myval{7}.addone();
    std::cout << moved_value.i[0] << std::endl;

    //Const reference is supposed extend the lifetime of a temporary object
    const auto& u = myval{7};
    //Prints 7, as expected
    std::cout << u.i[0] << std::endl;

    const auto& v = myval{7}.addone();
    //Why does this print 0?
    std::cout << v.i[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

1. Given what the explanation might be for this, is it possible to make this work so that the assignment "`const auto& v = ....`" works?
2. Why does the following assignment work when my doesn't?

   ```
   const auto& s = std::string("hi")[1];
   std::cout << s;
   ```

Answer (score 6):

A const reference only extends the lifetime of function local temporaries.  In the line

```
const auto& v = myval{7}.addone();
```

your reference is not binding to a temporary.  `addone` returns by reference which means you are working with a lvalue instead of a temporary and consequently when the full expressions ends you are left with a reference to an object that no longer exists.

---

Regarding edits.  To make

```
const auto& v = myval{7}.addone();
```

I would change `addone` to return by value like

```
myval addone() && {
    i[0]++;
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

This will then give you the correct behavior as it moves the object into a temporary that you then extend the lifetime.

For

```
const auto& s = std::string("hi")[1];
std::cout << s;
```

You code has undefined behavior and unfortunately you get what you expect.  You are doing the same thing as the previous example and you get no lifetime extension of the temporary string you created.

Comment: I don’t get why addone() returns by reference. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @OblivionreinstateOurMonica the signature is `myval&& addone() &&`.  the `myval&&` part means it returns an rvalue reference.

Comment: so you are saying in this case reference and rvalue reference are the same thing?

Comment: @OblivionreinstateOurMonica Yes.  Rvalue and lvalue references are both references.  It is that referenceness that makes them lvalues.  That's why you have to use `std::move` on rvalue references in order to move the thing they refer to.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I've added some edits (see end of post) to my OP. Feel free to expand your answer if you know the answers to my questions.

Comment: @DDaniel Your code doesn't "work".  You have undefined behavior and and unfortunelty the result you expect is part if the set of possible results.

Comment: @DDaniel See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb465f0af02d024a

Comment: @DDaniel No problem.  I've add that and you other follow question to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reference lifetime extension only works when applied directly to <s>the forehead</s> a temporary object.

There is no reference lifetime extension when applied to a reference.

```
myval&& addone() && {
    i[0]++;
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

the returns a reference.  (rvalue and lvalue references are both kinds of reference)

```
const auto& v = myval{7}.addone();
```

this doesn't do reference lifetime extension, because we are binding a `const auto& v` to a reference, not a temporary.

---

How can we make it work?  Well, rewriting `addone`'s signature we get:

```
myval addone() && {
    i[0]++;
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

now it returns a prvalue instead of a reference.

```
const auto& v = myval{7}.addone();
```

now this reference lifetime extends.

Your "why does this work" followup is because undefined behavior can do anything, including "appear to work".  It isn't valid code.

Comment: In your example where it returns a prvalue instead of a reference, should it still say 
`return std::move(*this)` or `return *this;`? What would the difference be?

Comment: @DDaniel If you `return *this` you return by copy:  `*this` is an lvalue even in an rvalue-qualified method.  If you `return std::move(*this)` you return by move-construction.  What a prvalue **is** varies between [tag:C++14] and [tag:C++17] in a way that is beyond the scope of this question, so my wording has to be careful.